# Condition windowing function

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, windowing, partition-by

Assume this query,

```
SELECT  
    SUM (Quantity) OVER (Partition By Symbol ORDER BY PositionID ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as RemainedQty
```

Is it possible to define conditions in the windowing function? 
In this example I need to get SUM (Quantity) under different circumstances in each row.
Something (hypothetically) like:

```
SELECT
SUM (Quantity) OVER (Partition By ...) Where SomeColumn='X' as RemainedQty_X,
SUM (Quantity) OVER (Partition By ...) Where SomeColumn='Y' as RemainedQty_Y ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Select SUM (case when SomeColumn='X' then Quantity else 0 end) as sumx, SUM (case when SomeColumn='y' then Quantity else 0 end) as sumy from table